# Initialize Lazy<T> with a known Value

Tags: c#, lazy-initialization

Question (TL;DR) in this constructor:

```
  internal AnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals, AnimalFlags aggregatedFlags)
  {
    AnimalList = animals;
    _lazyAggregatedFlags = new Lazy<AnimalFlags>(() => aggregatedFlags);
    var temp = _lazyAggregatedFlags.Value; // <<< ensure IsValueCreated == true
  }
```

How can I avoid the overhead of initializing a brand new instance of Lazy just to immediately evaluate it, causing it to tear down most of the internal structures it just created, similar to `Task.FromResult(...)` when using tasks?

---

Context and further details:

Suppose I have an object representing a collection of animals (this is a re-mapping of my actual code to something question-friendly, so apologies that the structure is a bit odd for describing animals...).

```
[Flags]
enum AnimalFlags
{
  Carnivorous = 1,
  Prey = 2,
  // etc.
}

public abstract class Animal
{
  internal abstract AnimalFlags Flags { get; }
  public bool IsCarnivorous => (Flags & AnimalFlags.Carnivorous) != 0;
  // etc.
}

public class AnimalCollection
{
  internal AnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals)
  {
    AnimalList = animals;
  }

  public IReadOnlyList<Animal> AnimalList { get; }
}


public static class AnimalHelper
{
  // Caller is expected to provide a known and immutable list of animals (not merely read-only)
  // This simply wraps it up as an AnimalCollection.
  static AnimalCollection GetAnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals) => new AnimalCollection(animals);

  // Caller supplies animals, we create an animal collection from them and must enumerate all animals in the process.
  static AnimalCollection CreateAnimalCollection(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
  {
    return GetAnimalCollection(animals.ToList());
  }
}
```

`GetAnimalCollection` is used extensively in existing code. There are very large collections of existing animals, where we want to pre-populate an animal collection using one. Also assume some other classes implementing IReadOnlyList that allow subsets to be selected without enumerating the whole list, etc.

Rather than enumerating all animals in the collection that allows callers to completely skip the collection if it doesn't contain any carnivorous animals, I'd like to add a property to the AnimalCollection. A naive implementations could add a simple property like:

```
  public bool IsAnyCarnivorous => AnimalList.Any(a => a.IsCarnivorous);
```

But it makes more sense to aggregate the flags once, using Lazy, for example:

```
public class AnimalCollection
{
  internal AnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals)
  {
    AnimalList = animals;
    _lazyAggregatedFlags = new Lazy<AnimalFlags>(() => AnimalList.Aggregate(default(AnimalFlags), (flags, animal) => flags | animal.Flags));
  }

  Lazy<AnimalFlags> _lazyAggregatedFlags;

  public bool IsAnyCarnivorous => (_lazyAggregatedFlags.Value & AnimalFlags.Carnivorous) != 0;

  public IReadOnlyList<Animal> AnimalList { get; }
}
```

However, when using `CreateAnimalList`, we now enumerate the list twice - once to create the list, and again to get the aggregated flags. That's a little inefficient, so we can change the `ToList()` shortcut to build the list ourselves and get the aggregated flags at the same time:

```
  static AnimalCollection CreateAnimalCollection(IEnumerable<Animal> animals)
  {
    var animalsList = new List<Animal>((animals as ICollection)?.Count ?? (animals as IReadOnlyList<Animal>)?.Count ?? 0);
    AnimalFlags aggregatedFlags = 0;
    foreach(var animal in animals)
    {
      animalsList.Add(animal);
      aggregatedFlags |= animal.Flags;
    }
    return GetAnimalCollection(animalsList, aggregatedFlags);
  }
```

Adding a new constructor to `AnimalCollection`:

```
  internal AnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals, AnimalFlags aggregatedFlags)
  {
    AnimalList = animals;
    _lazyAggregatedFlags = new Lazy<AnimalFlags>(() => aggregatedFlags);
    var temp = _lazyAggregatedFlags.Value; // <<< ensure IsValueCreated == true
  }
```

This constructor could also be used in other contexts, such as when combining collections of animals (and therefore combining their aggregated flags), which can then be very quick operations.

However, it seems to have made a bit more work for itself than necessary.

If, instead of `Lazy<T>`, I'd been using a `Task<T>`, I would be able to use `Task.FromResult(aggregatedFlags)` to avoid the additional overhead of creating a complex object to contain an already-known value. I can't see an equivalent way to instantiate a `Lazy<T>` from a known value already in hand. Am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you using `Lazy<T>` at all? Why not simply `var temp = aggregatedFlags;`?

Comment: The purpose of `Lazy<T>` is "I know how to get a T. I don't need it right now, but I'd like to store the workflow on how to get the T, so I can get a T if I happen to need it at a later time". It looks like you're using it like "I know how to get a T, so I store the workflow to get it but then immediatelly execute that workflow, because I need it _right now_." -- If you _know_ how to get a `T` and you also _need_ that `T` right now, then just execute the workflow to get it immediately. No need for a `Lazy<T>` at all, as far as I see.

Comment: @corak the need for a Lazy<T> arises when using the **other** constructor where the value is **not** immediately available, and may never be needed. It avoids ever having to enumerate the list. However, when we're already enumerating the list or otherwise already have the value in-hand, and the class structure already uses a `Lazy<T>`, the overhead (as in the question code) does indeed seem a bit silly, which is why I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: @Corak the line `var temp = _lazyAggregatedFlags.Value;` is simply to force the newly-instantiated `Lazy<T>` to have `IsValueCreated == true` (other properties in real code assume that it's expensive to access `Lazy<T>.Value`, and some have an alternative path in case `IsValueCreated == false`)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Why not populate the value already. You could have a `private AnimalFlags? _preAggregatedFlags;` which you could set in the Constructor where you know it already. And then change `IsAnyCarnivorous` to `(_preAggregatedFlags.HasValue ? _preAggregatedFlags.GetValueOrDefault() : _lazyAggregatedFlags.Value) & [...]` and if you're clever, you can store the `Value` of the `_lazy[...]` in that new field to make it even faster the next time.

Comment: @Corak That seems worse - now instead of storing and checking one field, we're storing and checking two fields on every access... and having to add extra code to resynchronise them. Unless I've misunderstood you, the "if you're clever" bit essentially means "re-implement the functionality of `Lazy<T>` yourself, finding a thread-safe way to populate the other field.

Comment: Well, you have to die one death. Either always use a `Lazy<T>`, then `() => value` is not that much overhead. Or always pre-aggregate the value immediately, even if  you might not need it. Or having some mixture of both which might cause additional problems. Or create your very own structure and logic, if you think you need every last nanosecond of performance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218436/discussion-between-steve-and-corak).

Answer (score 1):

Best answer I came up with myself after the initial discussion, from reviewing a little more documentation and the reference source is to add `LazyThreadSafetyMode.None`, which avoids a tiny amount of overhead from acquiring a lock.

```
internal AnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals, AnimalFlags aggregatedFlags)
{
  AnimalList = animals;
  _lazyAggregatedFlags = new Lazy<AnimalFlags>(() => aggregatedFlags, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.None);
  var temp = _lazyAggregatedFlags.Value;  // <<< ensure value created on this thread before returning
}
```

This can be wrapped in a helper method:

```
public static class LazyHelper
{
  public static Lazy<T> FromValue<T>(T value)
  {
    var result = new Lazy<T>(() => value, System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.None);
    var tmp = result.Value; // <<< ensure value created on this thread before returning
    return result;
  }
}
```

... simplifying the constructor to:

```
internal AnimalCollection(IReadOnlyList<Animal> animals, AnimalFlags aggregatedFlags)
{
  AnimalList = animals;
  _lazyAggregatedFlags = LazyHelper.FromValue(aggregatedFlags);
}
```

The overhead of wrapping a value in a `Lazy<T>` is orders of magnitude less than the overhead involved in `Task.Run(() => value)`, which perhaps explains why the latter has a pre-existing `Task.FromResult(value)`. @Corak mentioned in chat that if you're working with .Net Core, [`Lazy<T>` has] a constructor that takes the T directly. This seems to me a syntax that would be likely to give confusion given other questions I've seen about `Lazy<T>` (e.g. someone may call the non-lazy constructor expecting it to work lazily)

In any case, absent anything obvious I've overlooked, I don't need to continue with nano-optimisations.

Comment: Is this `Lazy` going to be accessed from multiple threads?

Comment: @mjwills it doesn't matter. `LazyThreadSafetyMode` is only relevant up until the point when Value has been created, which in the functions shown occurs before the function returns the value to the caller, and thus before the object has the opportunity to be passed to another thread.

Comment: `The Lazy<T> instance is not thread safe; if the instance is accessed from multiple threads, its behavior is undefined.` makes me a little concerned. But perhaps I am misunderstanding.

Comment: `the Lazy<T> instance is guaranteed never to be initialized from more than one thread`. By design the "fast path" for `Lazy<T>` (where the value has already been created) never uses a lock anyway.